# How to write a file as my print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I wrote a program in Python 3 with bs4 to get the subcategories of Wikipedia successfully. Now, I can see the results as print, but I am unable to write the results in a file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:proprietary software'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
noOFsubcategories = soup.find('p')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------') 
print(noOFsubcategories.text+'------------------------------------------------------------------')
tag = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'mw-category'})
links = tag.findAll('a')
#print(links)

counter = 1
for link in links:
    print ( str(counter) + "  " + link.text)
    counter = counter + 1

with open('subcategories.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write(links)
```

Comment: Could you be more precise about the problem. What happens? What did you expect instead?

Comment: when i execute the above code in python3, the output file is empty. so, i posted the above question.

Comment: i solved the issue by the following answers and get informed as a learner.  sorry for my English. i never no to type except my language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a little change, put write under the loop, and each loop will write a link to file

```
counter = 1
for link in links:
    print ( str(counter) + "  " + link.text)
    counter = counter + 1
    with open('subcategories.csv', 'a') as f:
        f.write(link['href'].split(':')[1]+'\n')
```

out:

```
/wiki/Category:Formerly_proprietary_software
/wiki/Category:Freeware
/wiki/Category:Oracle_software
/wiki/Category:Proprietary_cross-platform_software
/wiki/Category:Proprietary_database_management_systems
/wiki/Category:Proprietary_operating_systems
/wiki/Category:Proprietary_version_control_systems
/wiki/Category:Proprietary_wiki_software
/wiki/Category:Shareware
/wiki/Category:VMware
/wiki/Category:Warez
```

better:

```
# do not need to open file in each loop, just put it above loop
counter = 1
with open('subcategories.csv', 'a') as f:
    for link in links:
        print ( str(counter) + "  " + link.text)
        counter = counter + 1
        f.write(link['href']+'\n')
```

Comment: how to get the above out, without "/wiki/Category:" ?

Comment: wow! how simple!! i used to remove the data by this method. filedata = filedata.replace('/wiki/wiki/Category:', '') Thanks indeed brother!.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, initialize a list of lists with indexes and link texts and then use the [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to write to a csv file. Note the use of [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) below:

```
links = [[index, a.get_text()] for index, a in enumerate(tag.find_all('a'), start=1)]

with open('subcategories.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(links)
```

---

And, you can improve the way you are locating the subcategories by using a single [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("div.mw-category a")
```

---

The complete code I'm executing:

```
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:proprietary software'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
noOFsubcategories = soup.find('p')

tag = soup.find('div', {'class': 'mw-category'})

links = [[index, a.get_text()] for index, a in enumerate(tag.find_all('a'), start=1)]

with open('subcategories.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(links)
```

After running this code the contents of `subcategories.csv` would be:

```
1,Formerly free software
2,Formerly proprietary software
3,Freeware
4,Oracle software
5,Proprietary cross-platform software
6,Proprietary database management systems
7,Proprietary operating systems
8,Proprietary version control systems
9,Proprietary wiki software
10,Shareware
11,VMware
12,Warez
```

Comment: but the first line of the output file is as follows. "F,o,r,m,e,r,l,y, ,f,r,e,e, ,s,o,f,t,w,a,r,e"  how can i avoid the commas?

Comment: @info-farmer are you sure you've used `writerows()`?

Comment: @info-farmer I've updated with the complete code I'm executing. Hope that helps.

Comment: i am learning python 3 for the past one week. I am from non computer science background. i learned about 'the use of enumerate()' thanks for the above guide lines.